# Retrieving POST data in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, webforms

I'm having troubles to make my program work correctly - here I explain :

- I have, on one hand a C# WinForms app which launches an instance of IE by using the "Navigate" method : `myWebBrowser.Navigate(myUrl, "_blank", intarray, "");`, with `intarray` defined like this : `byte[] intarray = BitConverter.GetBytes(id);`. On this side, it works.
- On the other side, I have an ASP .NET WebForms application which has to retrieve this `intarray`. I've tried this.

  ```
  if (HttpContext.Current != null)
  {
      if (Session["Authenticated"] == null)
      {
          var current = HttpContext.Current;
          byte[] postdata = getpostdata(current);
      }
  }

  private byte[] getpostdata(HttpContext CurrentContext)
  {
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      CurrentContext.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
      byte[] postdata = ms.ToArray();
      return postdata;
  }
  // Convert a byte array to an Object
  public int ByteArrayToInt(byte[] arrBytes)
  {
      if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(arrBytes);
      int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(arrBytes, 0);
      return i;
  }
  ```

The problem seems to be in retrieving the Data in the `getpostdata(HttpContext)` function... I get a byte array with length = 0 instead of the one which is sent with length = 4...
Does anyone know how to make it work ?

Yann

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working?

Comment: Could you be more specific on which part is not working? Have you attached the debugger and stepped through the code to see where variables are not what you expect?

Comment: What I get in `postdata` is a byte array which has a length of 0. Or I should get a byte array with a length of 4... So the debug stops in `ByteArrayToInt` function but the problem is in retrieving the POST data...

Comment: (Because the one which is sent has this length, indeed it comes from an int)

Comment: I would try to capture HTTP traffic and make sure that issue is when you  retrieve your data in WebForms, not when you post it to server

Comment: How do you do this please ? ^^

Comment: Personally i use HttpAnalyzer, but it is not free ... You can use free analogues like fiddler. It will show you all HTTP traffic and you will see whether intarray is really post from your WinForms application

Comment: @Disappointed
Fiddler got me this : 

`Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      340  (headers:336; **body:4**)
Bytes Received:  458  (headers:332; body:126)`

I think this means my intarray is sent like it should ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
var current = HttpContext.Current;
var sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Encoding.Default);
var postdata = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

above

Comment: Could you add some information to help us all understand why and how this solves the problem please?